# Relational data in Firestore + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a recipe backend to test firestore and so far I've managed to get the CRUD operations working for the users, authentication & hashing passwords. Now I wanted to make it so there are two tables: `ingredients` and `recipes` and was wondering the best way to go about this?

My plan:

1. Make `ingredients` with all the apples, pears, rice, etc. and fill up the table as usual.
2. Make `recipes` with an ingredients array that just points to the `ingredientId` of each of the ingredients. (one to many)
3. Make it so the users can place a single `review` on the `recipe` (one to many)

I've done something similar in MongoDb before but I can't find anything written about firestore + Node.js on this. For reference, in MongoDb I would do something like this for the `reviews:

```
  review: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Recipe',
    required: [true, 'Review must belong to a Recipe!']
  },
```

My idea is that I structure it like:

```
Recipe: {
   name: 'Yummy Cake',
   cooking time: '15 mins',
   ... other fields,
   ingredients: [
       { ingredientId1: '5',
         ingredientId2: '25',
         ...
       }
     ],
   reviews: [
      { userId1: '4',
        userId2: '3',
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I don't really know how to write that in a firestore-friendly manner. Any help is greatly appreciated! Also I'm using `firebase-admin` as the package.

Comment: Firebase if not mistaken is meant for simple I/O; relational database structures would be more suitable for a database that supports such. But someone do correct me if wrong. I would probably use an ACID compliant setup like MySQL or anything relative to make this happen properly.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK you suggest using Cloud SQL instead of Firebase for this then?

Comment: To validate data in Firestore, you can use Firebase's server-side security rules. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Ooh I did actually see that @FrankvanPuffelen, was just using Users as an example to learn simple CRUD operations using firestore. Thanks though :)

Comment: @ulkerbiscuits Yeah for sure, there's other options however but any ACID compliant SQL should fit your needs for relational data.